# Conditional linking of sections in a program using linker command file input to a linker?

Tags: c, linker

Is it possible to link conditionally(like an if..else) by using the linker command file?

Suppose i am having two  two conditions and i need to link two different section by checking that condition in the linker command file while linking?

I am using a custom linker (star core - a flavor of gcc) of Freescale.

__Kanu

Comment: Is this something that you could solve more easily with your build system (e.g. your makefile)?

Comment: no am using Code warrior ide and not make engine mechanism!

Comment: Just your build system seems *so* customized, that making one more customization is not a big deal...

Comment: but it imitates gcc from all corners!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how different or similar your custom linker is to the GNU ld linker, but you mention that your toolchain is similar to or based on GCC.  GNU ld allows you to specify a linker script on the command line using `--script=scriptfile` or a similar option. ld scripts can `INCLUDE` other script files (or script fragments).  So you can put your common stuff into `common.link.config` (for example) and have two separate linker config scripts that look like the following:

```
/* option1.link.config */

INCLUDE common.link.config

/* stuff specific to option1 follows */

...
```

Unsurprisingly, the script for option 2 might look like:

```
/* option2.link.config */

INCLUDE common.link.config

/* stuff specific to option2 follows */

...
```

Then instead of instead of passing a 'condition' via the linker command line, specify either `option1.link.config` or `option2.link.config` as the linker configuration script.

If you're currently not using a script because the linker in the toolchain has an appropriate default script built into it, you can dump that default script using `ld -verbose` and modify it for the starting point for your custom scripts.